# doesn't setup.py develop use wheel for install_requires?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I have the impression that (using setuptools):

```
python setup.py develop
```

Won't use wheels when installing required packages (specified in install_requires).

Questions:

1. is my impression correct?
2. is there a way to force it to use wheel?

I am talking about [this particular setup script](https://github.com/ninuxorg/nodeshot/blob/master/setup.py).

Comment: `python setup.py develop` doesn't use WHEEL for install_requires. You may find more info @ http://pythonwheels.com/

Comment: I've encountered the same issue and pythonwheels.com provides no information on this. @PralhadNarsinhSonar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason, setuptools simply wont use wheels. The likely explanation is that setuptools is older than wheels, and no one has updated it to use them.

Using `pip install .` works however, since pip is fine with wheels. In your case with `python setup.py develop` that would be `pip install --editable .`.

So, to answer your points:

1. Yes, setup.py/setuptools wont use wheels.
2. No, not at this time. But you could use pip instead of running `setup.py` directly.

Similar questions:

- [Can python setup.py install use wheels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983835/can-python-setup-py-install-use-wheels)
- [How to instrument setup.py to use wheel packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277731/how-to-instrument-setup-py-to-use-wheel-packages/42312024)