# pip / setup.py: dependency resolution does not use available wheels

Tags: python, setup.py

In my Python package I declare a dependency in  `setup.py` as follows:

```
setup(name="xxxx",
      install_requires=["pycryptodome<=3.3"],
      )
```

If I upload this package and run

```
pip install xxxx
```

pip fetches the source distribution of `pycryptodome` although there is a precompiled wheel available on PyPI. If I run `pip` like

```
pip install "pycryptodome<=3.3"
```

the wheel is fetched from PyPI and installed.

Is there a way to enforce `pip` to fetch wheels if available ?

I forgot to mention that I work on Windows.

Comment: Not quite helpful, but here is a related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686069/doesnt-setup-py-develop-use-wheel-for-install-requires.

Comment: have you heard about the command `pip wheel`?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko   this command only creates wheels.

Comment: If you uploaded sdist of your package, try creating bdist and installing `pip install ./<your bdist>`. Perhaps `pip` may fetch sdist for an sdist's requirement.

Answer (score -1):

There's a `--use-wheel` flag to `pip install`. Try runnig `pip install --use-wheel xxxx`.