# Can python setup.py install use wheels?

Tags: python, pandas, setuptools

I am using setuptools. Is there a way to have the following command use wheels instead of source?

```
python setup.py install
```

In particular, I have a custom package that requires pandas.  While pandas installs perfectly fine with pip (because it grabs the wheel), pandas won't install while running python setup.py (due to pandas having missing dependencies on my machine)

Or perhaps, how do other people handle pandas as a dependency in there projects? Must I include all of pandas dependencies in my setup.py file?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to use `pip` to install you project. `pip` is able to handle your `setup.py` correctly and will use wheels by default if available.

So you can try to replace:

`python setup.py install` by `pip install .`

That should work.