# How to instrument setup.py to use wheel packages

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel

In my `setup.py` I have a dependency for `numpy` (in `install_requires`).

Is it possible to instrument the `setup` function to use wheel packages rather then source ones and not compile the whole numpy?

Note:
When I do `pip install numpy` it downloads the binary package of numpy. However `python setup.py install` gets the source package.

Comment: What kind of *instrumenting* do you have in mind? `setuptools.setup()` does not support wheels (see https://packaging.python.org/pip_easy_install/#pip-vs-easy-install).

Comment: I want to use wheels when running `python setup.py install`. So I guess there is no option for that?

Comment: Not with current state of `setuptools`

Comment: Could you make an answer, so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wheel` package was [introduced](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#rationale) with the purpose of fixing the problems with source distributions that were used by `setuptools`. Although `setuptools` had their own [Egg](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-egg) format for built distributions that predated `wheel` by 8 years, `wheel` is currently [considered the standard for built and binary packaging for Python](https://packaging.python.org/wheel_egg/). As of today, `setuptools` [don't yet support the `wheel` format](https://packaging.python.org/pip_easy_install/#pip-vs-easy-install).